# Automated UI tests in EPiServer

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, episerver

How do you perform your UI tests on a CMS like EPiServer? Where the editor creates content based on Page Types, and you as a developer must test each page instance?

We are currently testing all our pages in EPiServer using dynamically created tests based on the respective Page Type. Our buildserver then every night generates the tests and launches the Selenium RC, ensuring that our tests are covering all pages and run each day.

It has been working for years, but some issues has arisen:

- It is based on Selenium RC 1.0.3, which now seems deprecated in favor of the WebDriver.
- The Seleniun RC seems to work only with older Firefox versions, when I upgraded to the latest (10), it stopped working

What I would like to do is find out either how to migrate to the WebDriver approach and retain the possibility to let the tests be generated on the fly, or be pointed to another setup that will bring me the same benefits.

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out Stefan Forsbergs project at https://github.com/stefanforsberg/EPiTest
Also read his blog where he has written a lot about testing UI in EpiServer at http://www.popkram.com/blog/

Hope that helps.

Comment: No description, website, or topics provided. 5 years since last commit :(